# Is there a way to set password entry via curses interface in terminal?

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, linux-terminal

For example when you forget to put sudo before "systemctl ..." insted of gui interface poping out I want a curses prompt in my termial. Something like pinentry but for sudo.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @music2myear so far I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, but mostly no, because this is not actually sudo.

When the *polkitd* daemon is verifying admin credentials, it invokes the password prompt through a back channel – the GUI is not shown by systemctl directly, but is part of your desktop environment that registers with polkitd to wait for any future password prompts.

While this prompt could be an ncurses thing (and systemctl in fact *has* a built-in terminal-based prompter and always runs it in such situations), there generally can only be only one per whole session. As long as your desktop environment has already registered its graphical prompter, the fallback terminal-based prompter that systemctl temporarily runs will never get used.

---

(PolicyKit is not like sudo or UAC – systemctl doesn't become more privileged or anything like that; it just invokes the requested action and the *service* decides "hold on, this action requires admin auth". The advantage is, well, that the program doesn't need to sudo itself, which used to be troublesome with GUI apps.)